# Useof "as" in "for of" in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic sorted Map object (SortedMap) which stores objects of all types which implement the  'MapItem' interface.

I also have a class Fringe which implements this MapItem interface which I store in my SortedMap.   SortedMap.list return an Array of the elements stored within.

In one application, which only puts "Fringes" inside the map, I'm trying to iterate the SortedMap array and do things with the Fringes.

Trying to construct the iterator, I tried this:

```
for (let fringe of this._activeFringes.list as Fringe) {
  //call various methods of Fringe class.

}
```

This generates a compiler error.

I can however do this without complaints:

```
for (let fringe of this._activeFringes.list) {
    let myFringe = fringe as Fringe;
    //call various methods of Fringe class.
}
```

Not so sure why the compiler complains about the type conversion in the iterator, but not on the conversion inside the body, but anyway wondering if there is some concise way to do this without the assignment being required.

Comment: Does `as Fringe[]` work?

Comment: Definitely can't *cast* an array to a non-array.

Comment: Yep, Fringe[] works thanks.  It wouldn't  compile  fringe as Fringe of this._activeFringes.list, but I should have realized that "as" modified the collection not the member.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause here

```
for (let fringe of this._activeFringes.list as Fringe) {
```

You should cast `as Fringe[]` instead.